# JOptionPane showInputDialog with custom buttons

Tags: java, swing

Can i use showInputDialog with my custom buttons or can i rename "OK" and "Cancel" button on showInputDialog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a bunch of variants of each [`JOptionPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) method. And choosing the one will usually give you access to the desired level of feature. In your case, you're looking for

```
public static Object showInputDialog(Component parentComponent,
                                 Object message,
                                 String title,
                                 int messageType,
                                 Icon icon,
                                 Object[] selectionValues,
                                 Object initialSelectionValue)
```

See its javadoc here: [`JOptionPane#showInputDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-). notice you won't change here the buttons colors (as they're look-and-feel dependant) but rather change their text (which is generally speaking enough, as you can also here set the icon displayed on dialog left side).

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [JOptionPane documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).

---

You can send an array of objects that define the buttons:

Show a warning dialog with the options OK, CANCEL, title 'Warning', and message 'Click OK to continue':

```
Object[] options = { "OK", "CANCEL" };
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Click OK to continue", "Warning",
JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
null, options, options[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create your own `JDialog`-derived class?