# JOptionPane with multiple buttons on each line?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, joptionpane

How would I go about displaying a `JOptionPane.showinputDialog()` with multiple `JButtons` on each line? I am not talking about the `Yes`, `No`, `Cancel` buttons but multiple custom labeled `JButtons` that displays in the content area of `JOptionPane.showinputDialog`?

so I would need to get the value of the button pressed from the `JOptionPane` as well.

Comment: You will some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223983/joptionpane-showinputdialog-with-custom-buttons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can place any `JComponents` to the [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), there I can't see any limits, `JOptionPane` is same [Top-Level Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) as `JFrame`, `JDialog` or `JWindow`, but in contrast with plain `Top-Level Containers`, `JOptionPane` has implemented return events from built-in funcionalities in `Integer` value, meaning buttons `YES`, `NO`, `OK`, `CANCEL` and `CLOSE` too,

put all JButtons to the Array

```
String[] buttons = { "Yes", "Yes to all", "No", "Cancel".... };    
int returnValue = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Narrative", "Narrative",
        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, 0, null, buttons, buttons[i]);
System.out.println(returnValue);
```

Comment: the problem with this is that my application seems to hang when the joption displays....like it's transparent and the application freezes on this line.

Comment: there are three issues 1) that code for brinking JOptionPane is out of EDT (you can see only toolbar with close button), 2) code for brinking JOptionPane is linked/miss_linked to null instance, 3) JOptionPane was disposed then int return NPE, and now you have two choices a) edit this topic with code that demonstrating freeze, b) create a new post c) maybe there are/is another topics about

Comment: i fixed it by using `invokeLater()`. okay the problem i now have is that the buttons are appearing side by side not one per each new line.

Comment: @Kim Jong Woo maaaan what did you do :-)

Comment: i thought buttons would appear on each new line. that is not the case.

Comment: @Kim Jong Woo much luck with that

Answer (score 5):

This is as close to wat you want as I can get you.

```
Object[] colours = {"Blue", "Red", "Black", "White"};

int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
    "Which colour do you like?",
    "Choose a colour",
    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    null,
    colours,
    colours[0]);

System.out.println("The users likes " + colours[n]);
```

Comment: same problem, app crashes on this line. the joptionpane window shows but none of the dioalog's content shows.

Answer (score 2):

You wanted buttons on separate lines? Here's a way to get that using `JOptionPane`. In this example, the text of the button clicked is used as the pane's input value. This is done by the action created in `createChoiceAction()`. The multi-line button panel becomes the "message" provided in the `JOptionPane` constructor.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;


public class JOptionPaneExample {
    public static final String DIALOG_NAME = "what-dialog";
    public static final String PANE_NAME = "what-pane";

    private void showDialog() {
        JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(createInputComponent());
        pane.setName(PANE_NAME);
        JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog("What?");
        dialog.setName(DIALOG_NAME);
        dialog.setSize(400, 400);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println(pane.getInputValue());
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private JComponent createInputComponent() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(new JLabel("Pick a Category:"), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        Box rows = Box.createVerticalBox();
        ActionListener chooseMe = createChoiceAction();

        Map<String, List<String>> inputs =
                new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        inputs.put("Cars:", Arrays.asList("Toyota", "Honda", "Yugo"));
        inputs.put("Phones:", Arrays.asList("iPhone", "Android", "Rotary"));
        inputs.put("Pets:", Arrays.asList("Dog", "Cat", "Sock"));

        for (String category : inputs.keySet()) {
            JPanel b = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
            b.add(new JLabel(category));

            for (String choice : inputs.get(category)) {
                JButton button = new JButton(choice);
                button.addActionListener(chooseMe);
                b.add(button);
            }
            rows.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
            rows.add(b);
        }

        rows.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(600));

        p.add(rows, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return p;
    }

    private ActionListener createChoiceAction() {
        ActionListener chooseMe = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton choice = (JButton) e.getSource();

                // find the pane so we can set the choice.
                Container parent = choice.getParent();
                while (!PANE_NAME.equals(parent.getName())) {
                    parent = parent.getParent();
                }

                JOptionPane pane = (JOptionPane) parent;
                pane.setInputValue(choice.getText());

                // find the dialog so we can close it.
                while ((parent != null) &&
                        !DIALOG_NAME.equals(parent.getName()))
                { parent = parent.getParent(); }

                if (parent != null) {
                    parent.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        };
        return chooseMe;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPaneExample main = new JOptionPaneExample();
        main.showDialog();
    }
}
```