# Java: Custom Buttons in showInputDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

How do you add custom text to the buttons of a JOptionPane.showInputDialog?

I know about this question [JOptionPane showInputDialog with custom buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223983/joptionpane-showinputdialog-with-custom-buttons), but it doesn't answer the question asked, it just references them to JavaDocs, which doesn't answer it.

Code So Far:

```
Object[] options1 = {"Try This Number",
                 "Choose A Random Number",
                 "Quit"};

JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                 "Enter a number between 0 and 10000",
                 "Enter a Number",
                 JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                 JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                 null,
                 options1,
                 null);
```

[image: How I want it to look]

I would like to add a text field to this.

Comment: Could you expand on your requirements a bit more. Also, what do you have so far?

Comment: Referencing the javadocs (in this case at least) is the correct answer. No need to write here what others already wrote.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use custom component instead of a string message, for example:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TestDialog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] options1 = { "Try This Number", "Choose A Random Number",
                "Quit" };

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Enter number between 0 and 1000"));
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        panel.add(textField);

        int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Enter a Number",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                null, options1, null);
        if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textField.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: and how do you get the value of the input?

Comment: @ZuluDeltaNiner from the text field that is in the panel. Please see last edit.

Comment: If it was just a prompt and there was no textfield, how could one get the result?

Comment: @CardinalSystem you can use one of the variants of `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`. See [Getting the User's Input from a Dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input) for some examples.

Comment: How do I add buttons with shortcuts(hotkeys)  and perform actions on respective functions

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at [How to Make Dialogs: Customizing Button Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#button).

Here is an example given:

[image]

```
Object[] options = {"Yes, please",
                    "No, thanks",
                    "No eggs, no ham!"};
int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,//parent container of JOptionPane
    "Would you like some green eggs to go "
    + "with that ham?",
    "A Silly Question",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    null,//do not use a custom Icon
    options,//the titles of buttons
    options[2]);//default button title
```