# Swing Popup Frame

Tags: java, swing, popup, frame

Hello i have a program that should create a popup when the button is pressed and popup should contain text fields and buttons.I searched but i only found JOptionPane but it does not contain more than one text field so i need something else.
I tought that if i make a internal frame and make it invisible and when pressed make it visible 
`private void ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
InternalFrame.show();
InternalFrame.toFront();
}`

but it doesn't work so i need a code to make this possible(it doesn't matter if its frame or not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple Textfields and Buttons.

Refere below SO Questions and answers

[Multiple input in JOptionPane.showInputDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555040/multiple-input-in-joptionpane-showinputdialog)

[JOptionPane with multiple inputs on different lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834040/joptionpane-with-multiple-inputs-on-different-lines)

[JOptionPane with multiple buttons on each line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658576/joptionpane-with-multiple-buttons-on-each-line)

[JOptionPane showInputDialog with custom buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223983/joptionpane-showinputdialog-with-custom-buttons)